# Spring Boot Redis Mutiple Cache Issue

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redis-cache

I have a simple spring boot with redis application that i am building to cache master data of 3 entities emails, products and countries.
i have used the spring boot starter dependency

```
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
           </dependency>
```

also i am using started configuration in my application.properties file

```
  spring.cache.type=redis
  spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
  spring.redis.port=6379
  spring.cache.redis.key-prefix=masterDataApp
  spring.cache.redis.use-key-prefix=true
```

The cacheable methods are

```
@Service
public class MasterDataService {
  @Cacheable(value="EMAILS")
    public List<Email> getEmails() {
        System.out.println(" Loading Data from getEmails");
        return  emails;
    }

    @Cacheable(value="PRODUCTS")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        System.out.println(" Loading Data from getProducts");
        return  products;
    }

    @Cacheable(value="COUNTRIES")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        System.out.println(" Loading Data from getCountries");
        return  countries;
    }
}
```

The issue is once i load one of the methods from this class, the other 2 methods return the same data as the first method even though they return different Lists and have different Values Cacheable annotation. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have a keygeneratory. and add it to the annotation of the method.

This helps in segregating the caches

```
    @Cacheable(value="PRODUCTS", keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        System.out.println(" Loading Data from getProducts");
        return  products;
    }

    @Cacheable(value="COUNTRIES", keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        System.out.println(" Loading Data from getCountries");
        return  countries;
    }

    @Bean("customKeyGenerator")
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new CustomKeyGenerator();
    }

public class CustomKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        String key = target.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_"
                + method.getName() + "_"
                + StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(params, "_");
        System.out.println(key);
        return key;
    }
}
```

But the question still remains what is the value of value in the annotation as it does nothing to segregate the caches